# How do I mix Telerik RadControls with AjaxControlToolkit controls?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am working on a page that primarily uses Telerik RadControls, and thus uses the RadScriptManager control. However, I need to add some controls that use AjaxControlToolkit to the page, but since I cannot have two ScriptManagers on one page, so how would I do this?

Comment: I had this same problem at a previous contract, but I don't have access to the code to verify how I fixed it. It is possible though.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you cannot have two script managers on the same page.

However Telerik can use the standard Microsoft ScriptManager, and your Microsoft controls can also use the Telerik ScriptManager. You just have to choose which one you prefer. (I suspect you should try Telerik to start with)